# php Rounding up numbers (3628 > 3630)

Tags: php

After converting currencies I end up with the numbers below:

`3628`, `5987` and `2359`.

I'd like to round them up so they would appear as `3630`, `5990` and `2360`.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

My idea of doing this is adding a `0.` in front of the number to achieve `0.3628`, then using `round(0.3628, 3)` so that I would get `0.363` and then finally id have to remove `0.` and add another zero at the end to achieve `0.3630`.

There must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Your method only works if the original number is 4 digits long. It won't round 28 to 30, it will round it to 2800.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

`echo ceil(5987 / 10) * 10;`

outputs `5990`

Comment: Would this also work for 3 digit numbers? And number longer than 4 digits?

Comment: It works for any number: Your value gets devided by 10 and rounded up. Muliplying the result by 10 always gives you the number you started out with rounded up to the next tenner